# Problems in adding object from one view to a mutableArray in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Hi everyone I have been building an app and have met some problems.
My app has two viewControllers. One is MenuViewController and another one is MainViewController.

I want to pass a string from MainViewController to a mutableArray in MenuViewController, but have no idea how.

Here are my codes:

```
<MenuViewController.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *secondFavourite;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *secondFavourite;

@end
```

.

```
<MenuViewController.m>
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *menu;
@end

@implementation MenuViewController
@synthesize menu;
@synthesize secondFavourite;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.secondFavourite = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.menu = self.secondFavourite;

}
```

.

```
<MainViewController.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <social/Social.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imagepost;
    UILabel *predictionLabel;
}

- (IBAction)sampleSelector:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)showAllClick:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *predictionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *predictionArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *menuBtn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *fav;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *favLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *favourite;
@end
```

.

```
<MainViewController.m>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.predictionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hey gurl", nil];
}

//Add to favourite

- (void) addToFav {
    self.favourite = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.favourite addObject:self.predictionLabel.text];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.favourite);
}

//add to favourite button action

- (IBAction)addToFavButton:(id)sender {
    [self addToFav];

//pass data from favourite here to secondFacourite in MenuViewController (found on stack overflow)

    MenuViewController *menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    menuViewController.secondFavourite = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.favourite];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:menuViewController animated:YES];

}
```

I used NSLog to check that the menuViewController.secondFavourite in MainViewController successfully added the string into the array, isn't the array the same array in MenuViewController? Why doesn't the menu.tableView update and show the new string added? I am very confused and I hope someone will help me out.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the fact that your menu `viewDidLoad` is overwriting the value in these two lines:

```
self.secondFavourite = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.menu = self.secondFavourite;
```

That first line is setting your `secondFavourite` property to an empty `NSMutableArray` instance.  And since `viewDidLoad` will be called only after the view has been loaded into memory (in this case, when you try to push the view controller onto the stack), your initial values in the `secondFavourite` property will be lost.

Instead, you should move that initialization code into the an `init` method.

Comment: Thanks @andrew but I'm sorry, how do I move the initialisation code into an `init` method?

Also, my initial values in `secondFavourite` is empty, and the `addToFav` method will add object (a string) to `secondFavourite`.

I tried
`self.secondFavourite = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:secondFavourite];`
but still doesn't work.

Comment: @HenryNgan I believe you are having an issue with understanding the order that your code is executing. It would be most beneficial if you put a break point in your `MenuViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` and inspect the values of the `secondFavourite` property as you step through. What is happening, is that `viewDidLoad` is not called until your view controller is being pushed to the navigation stack, so that code happens after you initially set the properties.